# Installation of package 'ggplot2' had non zero exit status?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I am trying to install the ggplot2 package I am getting following errors & warnings.

```
 install.packages("ggplot2")
also installing the dependency ‘rlang’


There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
        binary  source needs_compilation
rlang    0.2.0 0.3.0.1              TRUE
ggplot2  2.2.1   3.1.0             FALSE

Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/rlang_0.2.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 754726 bytes (737 KB)
downloaded 737 KB

package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
        C:\Users\abhijitk\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpgtLRDo\downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘ggplot2’

trying URL 'https://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/src/contrib/ggplot2_3.1.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2863109 bytes (2.7 MB)
downloaded 2.7 MB

* installing *source* package 'ggplot2' ...
** package 'ggplot2' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 0.2.0 is being loaded, but >= 0.2.1 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'ggplot2'
* removing 'C:/Users/abhijitk/Documents/R/R-3.3.0/library/ggplot2'

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘C:\Users\abhijitk\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpgtLRDo\downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: running command '"C:/Users/abhijitk/Documents/R/R-3.3.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\abhijitk\Documents\R\R-3.3.0\library" C:\Users\abhijitk\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpgtLRDo/downloaded_packages/ggplot2_3.1.0.tar.gz' had status 1 
2: In install.packages("ggplot2") :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: update rlang, or more likely just update everything with `update.packages()`

Comment: Try `install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)`

Comment: ok will do that

Answer (score 1):

Just try to install the current version of "R" form https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/    and try install.packages("ggplot2") again. There is 90% chance that you will not find the problem any longer.

Comment: This solved my issue. R and RStudio running but R was out of date. I was on v 4.0.3 and the latest was 4.3.0. Thanks for this simple but super helpful comment.